# How do I redirect all requests that does NOT contain certain string to 400 using nginx

Tags: regex, nginx

I am trying to block or redirect to 400 all the requests which does not contain certain strings or keyword in the uri. I am looking for a solution using nginx. 
Specifically on "NOT containing strings". If it is not possible with ! (NOT) matching, is there any alternative.

Comment: There is `!~` operator in `if` directive.

Comment: Thanks Alex, let me try it out. I have multiple strings to compare against. If none of the strings are matching, the rule should sent a bad request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a map:

```
map $uri $bad_request {
    # start by assuming it's a bad request
    default 1;

    # if any of the following match, clear the $bad-request variable
    ~a-required-string 0;
    ~another-required-string 0;
    # ...
}

location / {
    if ($bad_request) {
        return 400;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! This looks to be the elegant solution for my environment as I have many stings to match. I may put the map into a file outside confg file and include it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try something like this:

```
location / {
    if (condition_1) {
        break;
    }
    if (condition_2) {
        break;
    }
    ...
    if (condition_n) {
        break;
    }
    return 400;

    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

If any of condition_1, ... condition_n match, `break` keyword prevent `return 400` and request goes to `proxy_pass`. If all conditions fail `return 400` will make nginx to response `400 Bad Request` error.

Conditions could be anything that [`if`](http://nginx.org/r/if) supports. E.g. `if ($args_pass = 1)` or `if ($http_user_agent ~ MSIE)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, This is a workable solution for sure, but using map seems to be much more simple when I have many strings to match.